# android screen adjusted no work in landscape mode

Tags: android, listview, resize, android-edittext, screen-orientation

I have find a problem in landscape mode. 
why screen adjusted no work in landscape mode? The Soft keyboard will overlay EditText input.

It's also have put this line to manifest.

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Empty"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="please input"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
        android:singleLine="true" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `RelativeLayout` it is better and more adjustable!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/android:empty"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="please input"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:singleLine="true" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: could you help to check this layout? it's also appear problem in landscape mode. http://www.sendspace.com/file/kvy0j8

Answer (score 0):

Try to Place `LinearLayout` of that `listView` in a `ScrollView`. This will resolve your problem.